# Delayed badge notification

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

I know that it can take up to 24 hours for a badge to be *awarded*, but this is not about that. It's about a delay in the *notification* for the badge.

Four hours ago, I received a notification that I got a *Nice Answer* badge on Mathematica.SE. Just now I got a notification that I got an *Epic* badge on CodeGolf.SE:

[image]

I thought it's weird to get *Epic* in the middle of the day, so I checked when the badges were awarded:

- The Nice Answer badge was awarded [4 hours ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question?userid=2305), i.e. when I received the notification.
- The Epic badge was awarded [15 hours ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/epic?userid=8478), i.e. at 0:00Z as you'd expect.

How come there was such a delay in the notification for the Epic badge? Was that a bug, or just a caching glitch that happens every now and then?

(In case you're wondering, the Nice Answer badge isn't really relevant to the bug itself, but it's proof that I didn't just overlook the notification for 15 hours. In fact, I also got a Nice Question badge on CodeGolf.SE this morning, which is listed in my "Recent Badges" *after* Epic, but appears further down in my list of notifications.)

**Edit:** In response to Rainbolt's comment, it seems likely that the script that awards the Epic badge always sets the timestamp to 0:00:00Z, instead of the timestamp of when the script ran (as seems to be the case for tag badges for instance). [Looking at SO, all Epic badges this year were awarded exactly at midnight.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic)

Comment: I have a feeling that the Epic badge script runs less often than the Nice Answer badge script due to the former being awarded less frequently. That said, it probably still "knows" when you earned it. This is just speculation of course.

Comment: Only more recently awarded badges are doing that (the midnight timestamps stop on page 4, somewhere around late-2012). There must be a bug somewhere that is causing the script to only record the date of awarding and not the time.

Comment: @animuson It could also be a feature, i.e. that the behaviour was deliberately change at the end of 2012.

Comment: I highly doubt that. Would not be consistent with *any* other badge in existence.

Comment: Note: epic and legendary and mutually consistent here; checking...